# JQuery ancestor td selector with particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem in selecting my ancestor with particular class,

I have different tabs with different contents particular div tag will be added if it gets any validation failure

```
 jQuery("table #sectionDisplay .ItemDetailContainerCell div").hasClass("error-label");
```

This will go very deep inside the tab so i just want get the outermost ancestor which is a td with particular name

I tried to use prevUntil,parentsUntil but no luck

I just want to get the previous ancestor until i found the td with particular class

Kindly throw some light

Regards
Sathish

Comment: use `closest()` or `parents()`

Comment: could you please provide the HTML and explanation according to it. It will be more helpful.

Comment: Thanks pranav this really helped  I tried with this  jQuery("table #sectionDisplay .ItemDetailContainerCell div.error-label").closest("td .tabContent ")

Comment: @Vijay,Ya i tried even in js fiddle to copy its very lenghy html content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting elements in ancestor level use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)**. If you want all the ancestor levels then use **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)**.

For the difference between methods refer : [`closest()` vs `parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#entry-longdesc)